# Powershell to Federate Office 365 domain

Tags: powershell, office365, openam

I am attempting to Federate office 365 and use it as a Service Provider, but I can't seem to change the SigningCertificate information in the FederationSettings. I am trying to use this powershell command:

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -IssuerUri $entity -LogOffUri $logout -PassiveLogOnUri $url -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol SAMLP -SigningCertificate $cert

This command only works if I remove -SigningCertificate $cert. And I can't change the SigningCertificate once I've set up federation either.  Also I am not using ADFS.  I really appreciate any help anyone can provide for why this won't work.

Error Message:

Set-MsolDomainAuthentication : Invalid value for parameter.  Parameter Name:
.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -IssuerUri $entity -LogOffUri $logout
-PassiveLogOn ...

CategoryInfo:OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDomainAuthenticaion], MicrosoftOnlineException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ProprtyValidationException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDomainAuthentication

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or it just doesn't work?

Comment: I am getting an invalid value for parameter error message

Comment: I think the error should also tell you what parameter is invalid.  Please add the entire error message to the question--that is very important information when asking for help here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the error message. It doesn't specify the parameter, but once I remove the -SigningCertificate part everything works, so I believe that's the issue. And I need to be able to change the value of the SigningCert.

Comment: Take a look at this--similar or same problem, no answer though, but may give you something for further investigation.  http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/613/t/193098.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else finds themselves in this situation the answer is to make sure all the spaces are removed from the certificate string.

Comment: Thanks!! You just saved from endless hours of Google search. Take into account that the documentation of Microsoft shows an example of the entire cert with spaces: [MSDN-Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194112.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :S